# Locating duplicate numbers in cells

Tags: matlab

I have a cell containing a number of arrays of numbers.

I need to find the duplicates (if any), and remove the shortest array, containing any duplicates.

Example: In `c = {[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [1 7 8 9]}` the number one is duplicate, and hence the cell should be `c = {[4 5 6] [1 7 8 9]}`, since `[1 2 3]` is the shortest array.

The size of the cell and the arrays varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `union` function, which does a set wise union on 2 vectors:

```
 c = {[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [1 7 8 9]}
 remove=[];
 for k=1:length(c)
     for l=k+1:length(c)
         if length(union(c{k},c{l}))<length(c{k})+length(c{l}) 
             if length(c{k})<=length(c{l})
                  remove=[remove;k];
             else
                  remove=[remove;l];
             end
         end
     end
 end
 for k=1:length(remove)
     c(remove)=[];
 end
```